# CSS - Positioning heading and text in centre of a container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a container with a background image, a `h1` heading and a line of text that needs to  the center. At the moment I've got the text centered but it's clinging to the top of the image/container. I've done this on another part of the site with just a heading and its fine, dead center. I can't seem to get an `h1` and a `p` to do the same. Here's the relevant code:

```css
section#about {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(../images/homepagemain.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

#about div.text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<section id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="index.html">WANT TO WORK FOR US?</a>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>MAIN HEADLINE</h1>
      <p>INSERT A TAGLINE HERE</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- some other code -->
</section>
```

Any help appreciated.

**UPDATE**

Here's the code for the full container:

```css
section#about {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(../images/homepagemain.jpg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

#about a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  /*   position: static; */
  float: right;
  background-color: #000000;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#about div.text {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}

.showreel {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: black;
  bottom: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.showreel,
.showreel>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.showreel p {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: normal;
  margin: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.showreel i {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.seemore i {
  margin-right: 30px;
}

.seeour i {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section id="about">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="index.html">WANT TO WORK FOR US?</a>
    <div class="text">
      <h1>MAIN HEADLINE</h1>
      <p>INSERT A TAGLINE HERE</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container showreel">
    <div class="seemore">
      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:#fff"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down fa-stack-1x" style="color: #000000;"></i>
      </span>
      <p>SEE MORE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="seeour">
      <p>SEE OUR SHOWREEL</p>
      <i class="fa fa-play-circle fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: The only thing that's not centered (vertically and horizontally) is the `<a>`. Your `h1` and `p` are.

Comment: Isn't your code doing exactly what you want? Even replacing your image with an absolute URL, the `<h1>` and `<p>` tags both stay centered horizontally and vertically. Could you please update your question to show all relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Yes the <a> isn't what I'm trying to centre, it's the h1 and the p.

Comment: Right, but the `h1` and `p` are centered using the code you provided. So there's got to more to the issue than what has been provided.

Comment: @hungerstar  I've provided the full container code.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I've provided the full container code.

Comment: I've just shifted your code to execute in a Stack Snippet, and it **still** displays the two texts in the center. You'll need to divide and conquer in order to isolate what is causing your problem, because it is not in your code above. Please update your question with the code that is definitely causing the problem in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that we can replicate the problem.

Comment: Very confusing. Could it be to do with a reset or grid file? I'm using reset & skeleton.

Comment: Possible. Are there any header or footer files included, or anything like that? I'd recommend copying just the above `EDIT` code into a new file, and then slowly importing other parts of your site until it breaks. That way, you'll know exactly what caused the problem. It may even help to link to your website itself for this question.

Comment: If you have a front-end site with multiple pages do all the pages need a header or is it just the index file?

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead [**right click and inspect the elements**](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/edit-dom) in the browser. You'll see which selectors are being applied to the elements and what files they come from.